# Keep H1 On Single Line

Tags: jquery, css

I have several divs

```
<div class="left">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
...
<div class="left">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Some of the titles are very long. The CSS behind the class is

```
.left {
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

The issue is that if the user resizes the browser, for the long titles, this pushed the content down so if you had 2 or more DIVs side by side with one having a short title and one having a long title, they wouldn't line up

Is there a way around this by either resizing the H1 tag or something else with containers

Thanks,

JJ

Comment: You could use @media-queries to change the font-size when the resolution comes across xxx pixels.

Comment: It's working as it should http://jsfiddle.net/jaP5F/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the css to this...

```
.left {
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The `nowrap` property should stop the text wrapping onto the next line, regardless of if it can fit or not.

Comment: Thanks - was using that but sometimes it bleeds into the other box. Having the font change dynamically would have been ideal. I think this is the best I can have though!

Comment: Try adding to your CSS: `overflow-x:auto' or 'overflow-x:hidden'. This will either scroll or hide the bleed.

Comment: As above, overflow should fix your further problems.  Glad this was helpful to you though (although you'd already tried it :p)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
```

I made you a Jsfiddle for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/guillaumek/7vaEa/

Answer (score 0):

Live with it or design it out of the page. Text is text and needs to wrap. If you use media queries you can make the divs stack on top of each then the 'problem' isn't so obvious. Or as one commenter says make the text smaller using media queries. You might find this useful: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/